# Query with id param returns wrong record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

When I run a query to retrieve a record from the database, I am passing an `id` param but it is returning with an incorrect record:

with this query:

```
    $idusers = \DB::table('users')
            ->select('users.*')
            ->where('id','=', $id)
            ->get();
```

I am passing `id` = `91TDFS78` and the result is actually for the record with `id` = `91`.

Comment: Is your table and your columns name the correct one?

Comment: I've seen this before.  What is the type of the `id` column?

Comment: its seems you have taken INT datatype for 'id' column?

Comment: the type is INT

Comment: What data type is your `id` column? If its `INT` that might explain your issue

Comment: _the type is INT_ Then the content of `id` CANNOT be `91TDFS78` now can it??? As you cannot have `TDFS` in an integer column!

Comment: @riggsfolly It is tape on the url

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what ___tape on the url___ means

Comment: exp : Type this http://localhost/doc/91TDFS78/works instead of http://localhost/doc/91/works

Comment: You just need to typecast  your $id variable like this : (int)$id

Comment: Make the question clearer and flows more logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all, I have to do the test before running the query

```
$isdigit = ctype_digit((string)$id);
if($isdigit){
$idusers = \DB::table('users')
            ->select('users.*')
            ->where('id','=', $id)
            ->get();
}
```